# Can't Access CouchDB Remotely

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ubuntu-12.04, netstat, couchdb

Please keep in mind that I have this installed on an Amazon EC2 instance running the latest version of Ubuntu Server.

I have changed the `bind_address` to `0.0.0.0`.

`netstat -an | grep 5984` yields the following:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5984            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

From what I've read about this, everything seems to be in order. However, for whatever reason, when I navigate to futon remotely, it doesn't resolve.

When I try to send a curl request to the database I receive "Couldn't connect to host at..."

When I send it from the server itself I get the response I would expect from CouchDB, so I know it's installed, just either it or my firewall is not configured correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

`iptables -L` returns the following:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5984

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: What is the (anonymised) output of **iptables -L**?

Comment: @tink I've added the information above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the port in your EC2 Security Group.

Comment: This was it! I actually figured this out right before I came over here to tell everyone. Thanks!