# Opened a new port :8083, but cannot connect from anywhere

Tags: linux, port, apache2

I have a remote ubuntu 14.04 OS  and recently opened a new port 8083 by adding two lines on the /etc/apache2/ports.conf as below

```
Listen 8083
Listen 0.0.0.0:8083
```

My public IP for my remote server is `52.24.182.161` and whenever I  visit `52.24.182.161:8083` I get an 500 internal server error, which I found out by looking at the access logs. 
But my `netstat -peanut` shows the ports is opened nicely for business.

```
tcp6  0  0 :::80      :::* LISTEN      0      1090145     -               
tcp6  0  0 :::8083    :::* LISTEN      0      1090153     -
```

So I dont know what went wrong in this as I cannot access any more information on my logs. Thanks. 
Below is the report of tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Sun Nov 20 16:36:42.788309 2016] [core:notice] [pid 29962] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 20 16:38:18.854098 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29962] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down 
[Sun Nov 20 16:38:19.919968 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30043] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 20 16:38:19.919990 2016] [core:notice] [pid 30043] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Nov 21 01:36:10.133501 2016] [:error] [pid 30049] [client 185.49.14.190:53876] script '/var/www/html/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: "500 internal server error" means something wrong with apache2 configuration.

Comment: Can you post the error from error log Do `#tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` and hit the URL from browser, Post here what you are seeing in log

Comment: Can you send a `grep 500 /var/log/apache2/ | tail` ? Seems like some php script is failing

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/491231/126632

Comment: @Vishal  I have added a link to the screenshot of my tail of /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0):

> script '/var/www/html/testproxy.php' not found or unable to stat

This error message indicates that the file `testproxy.php` can not be read by apache2 which in fact means on ubuntu OS that the user `www-data` has not the proper permission.

The following is *one way* to solve this and might differ if you have configured apache2 to run as a different user than `www-data`.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/testproxy.php
sudo chmod 640 /var/www/html/testproxy.php
```